# How to evaluate $\lim_{c \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-c}^c f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate:

$$\lim_{c \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-c}^c \frac{1+x}{1+x^2}dx$$

but I don't understand how to evaluate

$$\lim_{c \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-c}^c f(x)dx$$

How?

Comment: Consider complex analysis.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Observe that
$$
\int_{-c}^c \frac{1+x}{1+x^2}dx=\int_{-c}^c \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=2\int_0^c \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=2\arctan(c).
$$ Can you take it from here?

*Some details*. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\color{blue}{\int_{-c}^c \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx}&=\int_{-c}^0 \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx+\int_0^c \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx
\\\\&=\int_{c}^0 \frac{-x}{1+(-x)^2}(-dx)+\int_0^c \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx
\\\\&=-\int_0^c \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx+\int_0^c \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx
\\\\&=\color{blue}{0}
\end{align}
$$ giving
$$
\int_{-c}^c \frac{1+x}{1+x^2}dx=\int_{-c}^c \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx+\color{blue}{\int_{-c}^c \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx}=\int_{-c}^c \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx+\color{blue}{0}.
$$

Comment: How to get the second equality?

Comment: By parity: $\int_{-c}^c \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx=0$ You can see it by writting $\int_{-c}^c=\int_{-c}^0+\int_0^c=-\int_0^c+\int_0^c=0$ where we have made a change of variable ($u=-x$) in the first integral on the left hand side.

Comment: Can you elaborate that a bit. I've not heard of parity in the context of integrals before.

Comment: Sure. See my edit above. Tell me if it is OK.

Comment: Now why doesn't that apply to the first one?

Comment: Because the integrand $ \frac{1+x}{1+x^2}$ has no parity. Whereas  $ \frac{x}{1+x^2}$ is an odd function. Do you want me to elaborate in my answer above?

Comment: @mavavilj Look at the graph of $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$. It is an odd function, so the positive area on the right and negative area on the left will cancel. "Parity" is just another word for "signs."